# Generics in Java, Standard Values

Tags: java, generics

Ok, so I was reading the Java online tutorial for generics and I found this:

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

I have seen a lot of methods in Java use the "E" notation but I was looking for a method that uses the "K", key notation. Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres no real need to use K, V, E, T etc in your own classes but they are nice standards.

K and V for example are used by `Map`. A good example of K and V is a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)!

```
HashMap<K, V> hm = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

And implementing:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Answer (score 3):

java.util.Map is defined:

```
public interface Map<K, V> { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (`java.util.HashMap<K,V>`) uses it for example.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure a `Map` `K` uses  and `V`

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```